# Laravel 4.0 Using Codesleeve Asset Pipeline Downloding all Assets on Each Refresh

Tags: php, laravel, httpresponse

We've got Codesleeve's Asset Pipeline -- https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline -- up and running on our server but for some reason it's totally ignoring our .htaccess headers and its own cache setting. The config files looks like:

```
'cache' =>  array('production'),
'cache_server' => new Assetic\Cache\FilesystemCache(App::make('path.storage') . '/cache/asset-pipeline'),
'cache_client' => new Codesleeve\AssetPipeline\Filters\ClientCacheFilter,
```

Any help would be very much appreciated - the app is online is testing mode at http://app.nationalmachine.co

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP doesn't even know about your `.htaccess` file.  PHP just serves content to your server (in this case Apache), and the server parses the `.htaccess` file to determine the appropriate headers.  You can set headers in PHP, but if your server gets the last say on what is actually sent and can over-write any header attributes it likes.

With that said, the issue is either that the `.htaccess` file is not configured correctly, OR that content is being served with incorrect content-type header information so that it is not matching up with your `.htaccess` directives.

Looking at the site, images appear to be cached fine.  JS and CSS both have massive `Cache-Control:max-age=31536000` attributes, but are set to `Cache-Control:no-cache`.  I would guess your Apache `.htaccess` file doesn't have `'.js' and '.css'` extensions mapped for caching.

If that doesn't work, you might want to setup SSL/TLS on your site and test again to make sure there are not proxies that are playing tricks with your files.  It's not common for proxies to  turn off caching headers, but testing with SSL will at least make certain that's not what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I can see the headers you're talking about but I can't figure out where it's getting the `Cache-Control: no-cache` stuff. All of the expires headers are being assigned correctly from the htaccess file so it seems like that's working. Is there a way to override the no-cache setting?

Comment: Try: `<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</FilesMatch>`

Comment: Hm. Tried that and it still made no difference. I'm using the same asset pipeline on a different site, http://twothree.zone/ , and it's behaving in the same way. This one is driving me crazy.

Comment: Ok.  I noticed that PNGs are located at `/public/assets/images`, while CSS and JS both com from `/assets`.  Are these handled differently?  If so, please explain the how they differ.

Comment: Yep, exactly. The Asset Pipeline by Codesleeve creates the folders /app/assets/javascripts and /app/assets/stylessheets and then there's a dependency tree by which all JS and CSS files are combined, minified and served as one file. You're correct in saying that these files are treated differently in that they're compiled the first time, but then the application.css and application.js files are supposed to be cached. Caching is working in that they're not being recompiled every time on the server but for some reason those files are being served with the wrong cache-control headers.

Comment: From what I can tell after looking through the source code, headers aren't handled by the package.  You either need to set these at the router lambda function, or handle this via the web server.

Comment: Ok - when you say handle this via the web server do you mean that the settings would be server-wide? We have other people who host on our server so I'm hoping that any changes I make can be applied on a site-by-site basis. Thank you for all of your help + responses.

Comment: This would be done server side, but does not necessarily have to be done as a global configuration.  On Apache you can use the `.htaccess` file to setup caching for just that directory.  On Nginx, you can specify a location in the site's config file which will handle just a portion of the site.

Comment: I added .htaccess files to both of those directories and it's still being served with cache-control: no-cache headers. This is the most irritating issue...

Comment: You might not have the ability to set cache controls from the `.htaccess` file depending on the privileges inherited from higher directories.  This is something your dev-ops person should be able to check for you.  You need `AllowOverride Options` in the directory declaration.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your comments lead me to see that in fact the htaccess had no impact because the assets were, by design, not being served by the web server. I appreciate your time very much.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Codesleeve's Asset Pipeline sets the headers itself so no amount of .htaccess stuff will make any difference. Thank you BayssMekanique for your help in figuring that out.